# Can I pull correct values for a variable from an old spreadsheet into a new one that's missing those values?

Tags: excel, algorithm, missing-data

I have an excel spreadsheet with several columns, each representing different variables collected from various patients (rows). One of the columns is the unique medical record #, another is a unique visit identification #. The problematic one is "age." I must have inadvertently dragged and replaced the ages of about half of my subjects, since I doubt that >3000 of my 6000 patients are 54 years old.

I have the original file with correct ID# and age pairs, but I've done considerable work on this file and cannot start over. Is there a way in my new file to look at the ID# in column C, go to the old excel file, find that ID#, go over 3 cells to column F (age), copy that age value, go back to the new excel file and paste the correct age for each ID#?

I cannot simply sort both files by ID# and copy/paste all of the ages as a number of the cases have been intentionally removed and so the ID#s wouldn't match up because the total N is different.

I also have SPSS and R available to me, although I'm not particularly proficient with either.

Just, as an example, here's what the two spreadsheets look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgYxM.jpg

I've manually highlighted the bad values, but in reality there are 3000+ of them and manually checking would be very time consuming.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A VLOOKUP function should work here:

=VLOOKUP(C3,[OldWorkBook.xlsx]Sheet1!$C:$F,3,FALSE)

If you place this function in Column C, Row 3 of the New Workbook and then change "OldWorkBook.xlsx" in the function to reflect the name of your old Workbook, it should return the correct value from your old Workbook.

You can then copy that formula and paste it into the remaining cells in that column.

If the values are correct, you can copy them, Right-Click and select "paste values" to solidify them in your new workbook.

If I've understood your question, that should fix the problem. If not, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a VLOOKUP formula.

It should look like this (check if the cell references are right, and also the file and sheet name).

You should put this in a new column in your "NewFile".

The formula references the "OldFile" and should bring the value for the "F" column in the "OldFile" whenever the values for the "C" column are the same.

This example would be for the second row of the file (I am assuming the first row are column headers).

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,'[OldFile.xls]Sheet1'!$C$2:$F$6000,4,FALSE)
```